# Show data from table even if there is no data!! Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query which shows count of messages received based on dates.
For Eg:

```
1 | 1-May-2012 
3 | 3-May-2012 
4 | 6-May-2012 
7 | 7-May-2012 
9 | 9-May-2012 
5 | 10-May-2012 
1 | 12-May-2012
```

As you can see on some dates there are no messages received. What I want is it should show all the dates and if there are no messages received it should show 0 like this

```
1 | 1-May-2012
0 | 2-May-2012
3 | 3-May-2012
0 | 4-May-2012
0 | 5-May-2012
4 | 6-May-2012
7 | 7-May-2012
0 | 8-May-2012
9 | 9-May-2012
5 | 10-May-2012
0 | 11-May-2012
1 | 12-May-2012
```

How can I achieve this when there are no rows in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate table for this, you can create what you need in the query. This works for May:

```
WITH month_may AS (
    select to_date('2012-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + level - 1 AS the_date
    from dual
    connect by level < 31
)
SELECT *
  FROM month_may mm
  LEFT JOIN mytable t ON t.some_date = mm.the_date
```

The date range will depend on how exactly you want to do this and what your range is.

Comment: Hi eaolson. I tried your solution where I am storing dates from 1-31 and did left outer join mytable date column,but it will only show matching dates column.Could you please help me?

Comment: okay I got it working the other way round.and it gave me the matching result and the other results as null.Now my ques is I want all those null data to be the exact data from that table(the data is fixed fixed) and Message count column as 0

Comment: If I understand your question correctly and you want the first column to be 0 instead of NULL, you can do that with NVL( column_name, 0 ) for whatever that column is.

Answer (score 1):

First, it sounds like your application would benefit from a calendar table.  A calendar table is a list of dates and information about the dates.

Second, you can do this without using temporary tables.  Here is the approach:

```
with constants as (select min(thedate>) as firstdate from <table>)
     dates as (select( <firstdate> + rownum - 1) as thedate
               from (select rownum
                     from <table> cross join constants
                     where rownum < sysdate - <firstdate> + 1
                    ) seq
              )
select dates.thedate, count(t.date)
from dates left outer join
     <table> t
     on t.date = dates.thedate
group by dates.thedate
```

Here is the idea.  The alias constants records the earliest date in your table.  The alias dates then creates a sequence of dates.  The inner subquery calculates a sequence of integers, using rownum, and then adds these to the first date.  Note this assumes that you have on average at least one transaction per date.  If not, you can use a bigger table.

The final part is the join that is used to bring back information about the dates.  Note the use of count(t.date) instead of count(*).  This counts the number of records in your table, which should be 0 for dates with no data.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a left outer join *IF* you had another table to join to that contains all possible dates.

One option might be to generate the dates in a temp table and join that to your query.

Something like this might do the trick.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempA (Col1 DateTime)
DECLARE @start DATETIME = convert(datetime, convert(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 121))
SELECT @start

DECLARE @counter INT = 0

WHILE @counter < 50
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TempA (Col1) VALUES (@start)
    SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @start)
    SET @counter = @counter+1
END
```

That will create a TempTable to hold the dates... I've just generated 50 of them starting from today.

```
SELECT 
    a.Col1,
    COUNT(b.MessageID)
FROM
    TempA a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YOUR_MESSAGE_TABLE b
        ON a.Col1 = b.DateColumn
GROUP BY
    a.Col1
```

Then you can left join your message counts to that.

Comment: No other table contains the dates.Its the only table, but I think generating a temp tables with dates and joining or merging might give me the desired result.
I am not very good with DBA language, so I'll generate temp data table(c#) with dates and merge it with the original one.Will this work?

Comment: yep that would work. I've added some sample code above to show how.

Comment: okay let me RnD your query and I will revert back to you.Thanks very much for guiding me.

Comment: I should point out that Oracle doesn't have temp tables like SQL Server does.